# Unable to install pg gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I'm trying to install the pg gem in my project but I get the following error when I run gem install pg, or if I run bundle install:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /home/ec2- 
user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r 
./siteconf20191103-5491-ro2ye0.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You 
may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log 
which can be found here:

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/pg- 
1.1.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

As you can see, I'm using Ruby version 2.6.3 and I'm on a Windows.
I'm trying to install the pg gem so that I can connect to the database.
I'm very new to all of this, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This does not look like Windows, it looks like Linux.

Comment: @anothermh - He might be using linux bash on windows: https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/

Comment: WSL is not Windows.

Comment: I'm using Windows but for this project I'm using the IDE Cloud 9 rather than gitbash, or Windows command prompt.

Comment: Although your computer may run Windows the environment in which you are running `bundle install` is Linux. Make sure you specify that for future questions.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `pg_config`, which means most likely the pg development package has not been installed.

```
apt install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://rubygems.org/gems/pg ruby gems site and copy the latest gem into your gemfile. For me that was something like gem 'pg', '~> 1.3.0.rc1'.